# TypeError when computing the min and max of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have this snippet of code and it runs smoothly:

```
import seaborn as sns
iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')
iris.apply(lambda col: max(col), axis=0)
iris.apply(lambda col: min(col), axis=0)
```

But when I try to get the difference between the max and min, I get an error: `TypeError: ("unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'", 'occurred at index species')`

```
iris.apply(lambda col: max(col) - min(col), axis=0)
```

I assume that with both `max()` and `min()` succeeded, `max() - min()` will succeed too. What is wrong with it?

Comment: What is output of your `max` and `min`? From the error i suppose it's `str` which cannot handle `-` operator.

Comment: Take a careful look at the dataset. Maybe put a few rows in your question. Not all the columns are numeric.

Comment: There is nothing strange about the message. Almost every traditional representation of this data I have seen lists the species in the last column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filter out string columns using `select_dtypes`, because you can't do arithmetic on strings (...right?!). You can then vectorize this using `pd.DataFrame.max/min`, without the need for `apply`.

```
v = iris.select_dtypes(exclude=[object])
v.max(0) - v.min(0)

sepal_length    3.6
sepal_width     2.4
petal_length    5.9
petal_width     2.4
dtype: float64
```

Well, if you know your dataset, the only non-numeric column in the iris dataset is the label (aka, the `species` column), so you can just,

```
v = iris.drop('species', 1)
```

And the rest is the same. Calling `pd.DataFrame.drop` does *not* affect the original dataframe.

Comment: Thank you very much! I am a novice switching from R to Python, and your answer is more than what I have expected. The dataset does have a column of strings which can be sorted (so `min()` and `max()` work fine) but we cannot do arithmetic operations on it.